# UI design dpi sizes issue at xxxhdpi Samsung S8plus

Tags: android-layout, material-design, material-ui

Helllo ,
I'm a ux\ui designer. I designed application at photoshop for xxxhdpi(2960*1440) for a mobile device 'Samsung s8plus'. Once i finished designing I've created an image sized 2960*1440 of my app to look at my design at the S8Plus phone. Than I cut all the icons + made a styleguide for the programmers, etc..
Anyway, the problem that I have is that the developer put all my cuttings and on the app all the cuttings that i made looks smaller than they should look (in a gap of ratio of 1.142)?! For example 56dp pixels of an circle action buttun on the programmed app wont be the 56dp size circle i have made, it looks smaller than it should?! please help me figuring our why, and what should i do?